# Server Tab not Showing in Eclipse ADT

Tags: android, eclipse

I am searching for server tab in windows show view and also in others but I could not find it anywhere.I have planned to work my app with web services and tomcat server.Do I have to install anything to see that tab or It is Not available in ADT .
I am using Eclipse with ADT version.help me ASAP...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think you need a Java EE version to be able to show the server view.

**Edit:**
You can install it in the ADT:
help > install new software
select the eclipse link (for me it is http://download.eclipse.org/releases/juno).
Search for Eclipse Java EE Developer Tools

Comment: really it wont work in ADT? So I have to install java EE version eh?

Comment: Yeah, it won't even work in the normal eclipse. It's part of the Java EE tools. Check the update on how to install them.

Comment: Oh thanks man I got it I thought I was unable to find It in my Eclipse .I will install and update it.There is no answer of it in google .

Comment: No problem! Once you have installed it you should be able to open the server view.